# Variable "x" which I mention outside the function has some problem I guess . Function is not accessing the variable don't know why

Tags: javascript, css

Variable "x" which I mention outside the function has some problem I guess . Function is not accessing the variable don't know why .
here is my javascript function  below if any one require my html code a can also provide

HTML Snippet

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col lg-3"></div> 
  <div class="col lg-6 text-center"> 
     <div id="1">shahmir</div> </div>
     <div class="col lg-3"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
    function add();
    var x=1;
    function add(x){
        var a=document.getElementById("input").value;
        
        x++;
        if(x==1)document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=a;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make todo list

Comment: I know functions are hoisted but put your function calls _below_ the function declaration, it's just awkward to have it above. Also the reason you're having issues is because you have a variable named `x`, but you've also called your function's parameter `x`. You're not actually passing `x` to the function so get rid of the parameter

Comment: and then stuck to this problem

Comment: You should remove the first "definition" of "function add" and note that `x++` will increment x, so the next branch (`if (x==1)`) won't be entered. You should invoke your function using `add();`

Comment: i just deleted the parameter but sadly it haven't work why ?

Comment: Can you post the html code too?

Comment: below is my html code

Comment: <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col lg-3"></div>
                <div class="col lg-6 text-center">
                    <div id="1">shahmir</div>                                                                        
                </div><!--col-->
                <div class="col lg-3"></div>
            </div><!--row-->
        </div><!--row 2-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables with same name x. When you are incrementing it inside function "add", it is taking the value of parameter "x" not the variable "x" defined by you.

If you want to fix this code. Do as below:
- Move declaration of x before calling function
- Replaces local parameter x with y
- Remove function keyword when you are calling function

```js
var x = 1;
add();

function add(y) {
  var a = document.getElementById("input").value;

  x++; // x will become 2, so check  for 2 in next statement.
  if (x === 2)
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = a;
}
```

Comment: i just deleted the parameter but sadly it haven't work

Comment: I have updated the code with comments, please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The function can't see the outer `x` because it has it's own `x` variable received as an argument, that's called variable shadowing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

I'm taking a wild guess of what you're trying to do:

```
<script>
    function add(){
      var a = document.getElementById('input').value;

      document.getElementById('1').innerHTML += ('<br />' + a);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i just deleted the parameter but sadly it haven't work why ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `x` into the function. This will make a new variable called x which will be used within the function. It is different to the `var x` defined above.

Change to

```html
<script>
  var x = 1;

  function add() {
    var a = document.getElementById("input").value;

    x++;
    if (x == 1) document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = a;
  }

  function add();
</script>
```

or if you want to be able to use the function in other places.

```html
<script>
  var x = 1;

  function add(x) {
    var a = document.getElementById("input").value;

    x++;
    if (x == 1) document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = a;
    return x;
  }

  x = add(x);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer `x` variable by declaring a parameter to your function with the same name.

Inside the function `x` refers to the parameter, not the global variable.

You also have a function declaration with no body:

```
function add();
```

If you mean to call the `add` function, you just do: `add()`.

Take the `x` parameter out of the function declaration. Also, your condition will never be true. Since you initialise x to 1, and increment it before testing it, it will always be at least 2.

This is *probably* what you are trying to do (it's hard to tell, but at least this will do *something*):

```
<script>
    var x=0;
    function add(){
        var a=document.getElementById("input").value;
        x++;
        if(x==1)document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=a;
    }
    add();
</script>
```